# Html\CSS - unable to align custom Select tag along with a custom Checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, html-select

I've created several custom checkboxes, where the first element is also a `select` element. I need all the elements to be in the same line, but in order to reduce the margin between each line I used `line-height=something` property, but this causes the text of the `select` element to be distorted\cut, so I lowered the text of the `select` manually but I'm unable to lower its checkbox as well.

HTML:

```
<div id="checkBoxesContainer">
    <input type='checkbox' value='valuable1' id="valuable1"/><label for="valuable1"><span></span></label>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="0">Test content</option>
            <option value="1">Content 1</option>
            <option value="2">Content 2</option>
            <option value="3">Content 3</option>
            <option value="4">Content 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type='checkbox' value='valuable2' id="valuable2"/><label for="valuable2"><span></span></label><div>qwertyu</div>
    <input type='checkbox' value='valuable3' id="valuable3"/><label for="valuable3"><span></span></label><div>asdfghj</div>
    <input type='checkbox' value='valuable4' id="valuable4"/><label for="valuable4"><span></span></label><div>zxcvbnm</div>
    <input type='checkbox' value='valuable5' id="valuable5"/><label for="valuable5"><span></span></label><div>qazwsxe</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* for the custom checkboxes!! */
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:block;
    visibility: hidden;
}

label span
{
   background-color: grey;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label span
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 20x;
    width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#checkBoxesContainer{
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

select {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -op-appearance: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 35px 0 0;
    line-height: 25px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    bottom: -15px;
    background:  url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat right center;
}
#checkBoxesContainer div{
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
    left: 65px;
    bottom: 15px;
    color: #cfcecf;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 5px
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu03xfp4/3/)

EDIT: this is what the `select` text look like when the line height is reduced:

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu03xfp4/1/

Comment: Could you explain what did you have to change, and what must I take under consideration next time I build something like this?

Comment: Removed unnecessary styles from select and that's it. Haven't changed anything else.

Comment: Seems I'm slow, here's another one that may help. http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/Lu03xfp4/4/

Comment: I should have added that the `select` font-size is 18px, and with my solution using the `line-height` attribute, the text gets cut, just like in the screen shot I have added, please see the updated fiddle and image.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen your solution works great, could you explain what were your changes to the code?

Comment: I can try, I sort of just threw everything at it. Ile write an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda just threw a bunch of stuff at it but here are some of the changes I made, can't remember what did what exactly but here we go..

(from top to bottom in CSS)

**input[type=checkbox]** - none

**label span** - none

**input[type=checkbox]:checked + label span** - none

**checkBoxesContainer**

removed `line-height: 10px;`

**select**

removed `position: relative;` and `bottom: -15px;`

removed     `line-height: 25px;`

added `margin-left: -10px;` to text aligned with margin left set in `checkBoxesContainer div`

**checkBoxesContainer div**

decreased width to `width: 400px;` so it fit

added `vertical-align: top;` so it aligns top with the checkbox, somehow

adjusted line height from 5px to `line-height: 20px;`

removed `position: relative;` and related `left: 65px;` and `bottom: 15px;`

replaced above with `display: inline-block;` and..

added `margin-left: 20px;` to keep it from the check box

for vertical spacing in your drop down I added..

```
option {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/Lu03xfp4/6/